# Show content of View Controller in parent view using Interface Builder only?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nsviewcontroller

I'm wondering if its possible to display content of ViewController (doesn't matter NS or UI) in "parents" view using only connections in Interface Builder (sometimes it is convenient).

For example take a look at this basic setup.

1 - MyViewController class created with XIB.

[image: MyViewController files]

2 - MyViewController's XIB contains its UI layout

[image: MyViewController's XIB layout]

3 - Custom ViewController instance added to MainMenu XIB

[image: custom ViewController added to MainMenu XIB]

And its class set to MyViewController

[image: custom class set to MyViewController]

4 - And what I want is to show MyViewController's xib layout in MainWindow's view without using `[mainWindow.view addSubview:myViewController.view]`. Can I achieve this using IB connections?

[image: MainWindows view]

Is it possible?

6 - Result should look like this, but without single line of code :)

[image: Result]

Comment: You don't need step 3. You can directly set the class of the file's owner as MyViewController. And I don't think what you want is possible.